# C# значения, выдаваемое индексатором

Tags: c#

Читая книжку Шилдта C# наткнулся на следующую информацию

> ...  значение, выдаваемое индексатором, нельзя передавать методу в качестве параметра `ref` или `out`, поскольку в  индексаторе не определено место в памяти для его хранения.

Не понимаю этого отрывка, ведь следующий код работает прекрасно:

```
  public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            int i = 5;
            method(ref i);
            return i;
        }
        set
        { }
    }

    public void method(ref int a)
    {
        a += 10;

    }
```

Что это вообще за значения, выдаваемые индексатором?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SomeMethod(ref obj[3]); // нельзя
```

Comment: Ну, кстати, не так уж и нельзя в C# 7...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, у Шилдта вряд ли по C# 7 книга :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Тогда и индексатор `ref int` какой-нибудь должен возвращать?

Comment: @Grundy именно так